# how run query while using concat function to get data from mutliple table

Tags: concatenation

I am trying to run the query on big data using newyork city bike dataset, but I am not able to see citibike_trips table.
I found data set fir NYS citi bike but table for citibike _trips table shows as empty no data available.

so while running the below query I am getting error as  Syntax error: Expected end of input but got "(" at [2:7]

```
SELECT usertype
CONCAT(start_station_name,"TO", end_station_name) AS route
COUNT* as num_trips
ROUND(AVG(CAST(trip duration AS int64)/60),2)
group by
start_station_name, end_station_name,user type
order by
 num_trips DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

I was trying to combine the rows from mutliple table city bike trip and city sation where
I will be able to see duration and number of trips for usertype
Syntax error: Expected end of input but got "(" at [2:7]

Comment: Which database system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There are commas missing between the select columns and the FROM clause is missing, too:

```sql
SELECT usertype,
CONCAT(start_station_name, " TO ", end_station_name) AS route,
COUNT * AS num_trips,
ROUND(AVG(CAST(trip duration AS int64) / 60), 2) AS some_column_name
FROM <some table of your choice>
GROUP BY start_station_name, end_station_name,user type
ORDER BY num_trips DESC
LIMIT 10
```